# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with javafxmobile-plugin ./gradlew createIpa

Tags: gluon-mobile

When trying to build a test app for iOS, I ran into the exception included below. There seems to be a fix for this here https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/issues/188, but I guess that fix somehow didn't make it into the fork I am using (excerpt from my gradle.build):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        //cc_init_javafxports check version:
        //  https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.8'
    }
}
```

I cloned the source of javafxmobile-plugin. 2 weeks ago, version 1.3.9 was committed:

```
changeset:   472:8491a50f2b76
tag:         1.3.9
user:        Gluon Jenkins <jenkins@gluonhq.com>
date:        Thu Oct 19 16:05:18 2017 +0200
summary:     new release: 1.3.9
```

But it has not yet been published.

Does somebody know if this javafxmobile-plugin v1.3.9 resolves the issue shown below? If not, is there a workaround, e.g. by renaming certain classes?

```
Caused by: org.robovm.compiler.CompilerException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at     org.robovm.compiler.plugin.lambda.LambdaPlugin.transformMethod(LambdaPlugin.java:242)
    at org.robovm.compiler.plugin.lambda.LambdaPlugin.beforeClass(LambdaPlugin.java:89)
...

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.robovm.compiler.plugin.lambda.LambdaClassGenerator.pushArguments(LambdaClassGenerator.java:203)
    at org.robovm.compiler.plugin.lambda.LambdaClassGenerator.createForwardingMethod(LambdaClassGenerator.java:134)
    at org.robovm.compiler.plugin.lambda.LambdaClassGenerator.generate(LambdaClassGenerator.java:79)
    at org.robovm.compiler.plugin.lambda.LambdaPlugin.transformMethod(LambdaPlugin.java:180)
    ... 85 more
```

Comment: Since the stack trace  contains `LambdaClassGenerator` and since I used

Comment: Since the stack trace  contains `LambdaClassGenerator` and since I used the dependency: `compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjavafx:2.2.0'` which heavily smells Lambda, I made an experiment and threw out this library and all code references to it. The result: no more error, build successful. Until further notice, I will fall back from calls like `JavaFxObservable.valuesOf(baseView.getScene().widthProperty()).subscribe(w -> centerView.setFitWidth(w.doubleValue()*0.85));` to event listeners.

Comment: Good to know that you solve it. I've tried RxJavaFX on iOS (plugin 1.3.9), with just your expression above, and it worked fine for me. Lambdas in general work fine. I wasn't adding `'io.reactivex.**.*'` to forceLinkClasses, though. When I did, I got the same exception you have posted. This means that some classes can't be linked, but it might work if you don't use them. Maybe you could try it again?